# batch apex finish method to schedule another batch job with scope of 100 due to callout limit

Tags: apex, batch, callout, schedulebatch

The schedule_batch_mdm_role_definition I believe is working fine.

```
    global class schedule_batch_mdm_role_definition implements schedulable 
    {
        global void execute(SchedulableContext sc)
        {
            batch_mdm_role_definition myBatchClass = new batch_mdm_role_definition();
            database.executeBatch(myBatchClass , 100);
        }
    }
```

In the finish method of the batch_mdm_role_definition I am thinking I need to schedule the next batch job aka batch_mdm_contact to allow for the previous job time to complete due to salesforce asynchronous handling.

This works but my challenge is I need to limit scope to 100 because of the callout limit.

Question:  How can I restructure this part to schedule the next job and respect the 100 callout limit.

```
public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc)
    {               
      string cronID = System.scheduleBatch(new batch_mdm_contact(), 'Chained Sync Handle', 2);
    }
```

Additional Insight: The batch_mdm_contact class can query for thousands of records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you want to limit the scope, you'll want to call the class in this manner:

```
string chronId = system.scheduleBatch(batchable, jobName, minutesFromNow, scopeSize);
```

See [ApexDocumentation for Schedulable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm?search_text=schedulable) which explains the subject in more depth.

I don't know that you would need to implement the schedulable interface as @AdrianLarson suggests since you can call this directly and the job would be added to the end of the FlexQueue. I would recommend that you first check for available limits in the Queue before calling this method.